# Java, using another java program in jar format

Tags: java, jar

i want to embed an open source editor to my java desktop application. But i am not sure yet how to do it. I got jnlp web start and jar file to import library.
The program which will be imported is like below.
[image]
In fact i just need internal frames but if it is too completed i can embed whole program too.
I think about 3 options but don't know which one really works and which one is better.

1. Run jnlp webstart in java code
2. Run jar file in java code(non-executable jar)
3. Import jar and use its api (This is really what i need but i m not sure how to do this. I debugged the code to understand which frame works how but i have no experience about it and i found it very complicated)

Any advices how to solve this problem ?

Thanks,
Bilal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture just shows the view but there's more behind. You can't just embed the internal frames into you application and use the editors functionality. You'll need all the model, controller, support, ... classes too.

You may be lucky, that the main frame is just a simple container and you can "replace" it with your own container. But I not too optimistic. I don't think, that the editor has an API that allows integrating the internal frames into another container. So Option 3 would be the best but I think it's out of reach. Is it a common editor? Maybe more help is possible if you just tell us its name.

Comment: Yes the editor doesn't have an API that allows integrating internal frames. This isn't a common editor. This is a gene editor, which is used in bioinformatik. To do 3 Option i tried debugging and finding what i needed but i don't know if I am doing this right way. How can i do it better?

Comment: @bilal if Bioinformatik is open source, contact its maintainer.  Maybe he can help you.

Comment: the editor uses Bioinformatik API and does already what i want. i just need to embed editor to my app.

Comment: so i have chosen option 3 and it will be a little complicated, i am taking look of code and it is getting better. thanks for your advices